# How to create a Postgresql database query in Django with BitXor bitwise comparison and filtering by Hamming distance value?

Tags: python, django

My task is to develop a function for searching images in a database using perseptual hash and Hamming distance comparison.
The code below works, but due to the fact that filtering occurs in the Django environment and Python, the code runs extremely slowly,
on average the execution time is more than 7 seconds with 1,500,000 records in the database,
but the number of records on the production server will be much larger and the request processing speed will drop even more.

models.py

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Fids(models.Model):
    """
    The model stores records with computed image hashes (>6000000 records)
    picture = 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Sc835208f704548b7b230fd12f72850bfU.jpg'
    hs8 = '9aca3edfc0c23538'
    bin8 = '1001101011001010001111101101111111000000110000100011010100111000'
    """
    picture = models.URLField()
    hs8 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bin8 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

service.py

```
# service.py
import requests
import json
import imagehash
from PIL import Image
from main.models import Fids


def hamming_distance(binary_str1, binary_str2):
    """
    The function calculates the Hamming distance
    example input:
    binary_str1 = '1001101011001010001111101101111111000000110000100011010100111000'
    binary_str2 = '1001101011001010001111101101111111000000110000100011010100111000'
    """
    if len(binary_str1) != len(binary_str2):
        return -1
    xor_result = int(binary_str1, 2) ^ int(binary_str2, 2)
    hamming_distance = bin(xor_result).count('1')
    return hamming_distance


def search(url=None, hamming=None):
    """
    Search query processing function
    
    example input:
    url = 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Sc835208f704548b7b230fd12f72850bfU.jpg'
    hamming = 8

    output:
    delay: 8-15 sec
    """
    if url is None:
        return -1
    hamming = 0 if hamming is None else int(hamming)
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
        hash = imagehash.phash(Image.open(res), hash_size=8)
        str_hash = str(hash)
        binary = bin(int(str_hash, 16))[2:].zfill(len(str_hash)*4)
    except Exception as er:
        return json.dumps({'search': url, 'error': str(er)})
    result = []
    queryset = Fids.objects.all().values('picture', 'bin8')
    for item in queryset:
        bin8 = item['bin8']
        bin8 = '' if bin8 is None else bin8
        distance = hamming_distance(binary, bin8)
        if 0 <= distance <= hamming:
            result.append({'url': item['picture']})
    return json.dumps({'search': url, 'results': result})
```

I think that you need to correctly compose the SQL query so that filtering is carried out using the Postgreql-14 database.
I found the BitXor aggregation function in Django: `from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import BitXor`

I believe that it performs a bitwise comparison, but I don’t understand how to apply it, there are very few examples on the Internet,
Moreover, you also need to filter the request by Hamming disorder.

SQL also has the # operator, which also performs a bitwise comparison.
Something like: `SELECT X'eb35b232b08ac33e' # X'eb35b232b08ac33e';`
But I don’t understand how to apply this to my problem.

Help me create the correct query using ORM Django or SQL query to perform search and filtering using bitwise comparison and comparing the result with a given Hamming distance value.

Comment: Here's a cross-site dupe that shows how to create a very similar index for fast searches: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72134/fast-hamming-distance-queries-in-postgres. You're out of luck with "django orm", "non-standard query" and "performance" in one sentence - either replace "orm" with "raw sql" or drop "performance".

Comment: I've rolled back your edit since you have added an answer into the question body. I see you have also posted (and deleted) the same thing as an answer. Please undelete one of them if you want to share an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I found this solution:

```
SELECT id, hsi7 
FROM main_fids 
WHERE length(regexp_replace(((hsi7 # 524383500174776)::bit(64))::text, '0', '', 'g')) < 8 ;
```

I convert the result of bit XOR to a binary type, then convert it to a string, remove zeros, count the number of characters in the resulting string, thus obtaining the Hamming distance, compare it with the specified value (in example 8). The query is still very slow; it might be worth changing the query or table structure somehow, or converting the data to a different type.
If possible, please recommend a more elegant and efficient solution.
Please.